# Unable to set state with an external widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter and trying to change the state of an icon (switching icons) when I tap over it. This works fine if everything is on the same class. But I am repeating part of the widget across repeated pages thus I have moved out that Widget to another class. Now when I try to set state by passing in a function, based on the debug step through, looks like it is working fine but the state remains the same (icon does not change). Can I know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

This is the class where I am calling the widget from another class and passing in the function to set state.

```
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  IconData heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.heart;

  void setFav(){
    print('clicked');
    setState(() {
      if (heartStatus == FontAwesomeIcons.heart) {
        heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart;
      } else {
        heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.heart;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Page page = new Page();
    PageController controller = PageController();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            // this is the external widget repeated 3 times. Each time passing in setFav which is the setState function. 
            page.getPageData("text 1", "", setFav),
            page.getPageData("text 2", "", setFav),
            page.getPageData("text 3", "", setFav),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class which provides the widget via page.getPageData (I have removed alot of the nested widgets to focus on the ones that matters for this set state issue, the Icons).

```
class Page{

  Widget getPageData(String question, String answer, Function setFav){
    IconData heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.heart;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(heartStatus),
                onTap: () {
                  setFav();
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shareAlt),
                onTap: () {
                  print('shared');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are providing `setFav` method, which calls the `setState` to change your icon in `MyPage` widget.

I think your goal is to change the icon in the widget that returns from the `getPageData` method.

After changing the icon in the MyPage with the `setFav` method, you are not using this icon. Your widgets in the PageView are not using that icon.

I highly suggest that you use a widget, rather than function.
https://iirokrankka.com/2018/12/11/splitting-widgets-to-methods-performance-antipattern/

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  Page({this.changeIcon, this.heartStatus});

  Function changeIcon;
  IconData heartStatus;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(heartStatus),
                onTap: () {
                  changeIcon();
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shareAlt),
                onTap: () {
                  print('shared');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
child: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            // this is the external widget repeated 3 times. Each time passing in setFav which is the setState function. 
            Page(heartStatus,setFav);
            Page(heartStatus,setFav);
            Page(heartStatus,setFav);
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Tried with your suggestion and the set state does kinda works but the state affects all 3 pages. If I click on page one the heart changes to solid on all 3 pages.

Comment: Because children are sharing the same state from parent. It's the correct behavior. Maybe you can hold array of IconData and pass the IconData's with index.